# How often can I switch the micro SD card?

Tags: hardware, sd-card, pi-2

I have the Pi 2 and I bought a bunch of micro SD cards, one for each OS available. I switch the SD cards often (~3 times per day, sometimes more) and I'm wondering if there's a replacement limit of the connectors in Pi 2.

The noise when I insert or remove an SD card is not very promising...

Comment: My guess is they are rated for dozens of insertions and removals.  but your mileage may vary, so use Win32DiskImager and make a copy of it on you hard drive just in case.

Comment: @SDsolar: I don't care about the SD card, I care about the Raspberry. If the raspberry SD slot is broken, a disk image doesn't help me that much.

Comment: The accepted answer and comment are right on the mark.  It is more than 5000-10,000 insertions and removals at 400-600 cycles per hour, depending on the model.  Here it is, on page 2:  www.mouser.com/ds/2/185/e60900232-38395.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite a while, but I remember reading the mechanical specs for various USB connectors. The micro-usb was 10,000 insertions, which is better than others. I don't think these applied to the sockets, which are presumed to last longer.

Whatever the actual number, I don't think you are likely to reach the limit.

Comment: You're right on the mark.  According to Mouser, the resistance of the sockets are good past about 10,000 cycles.  Here's a spec sheet - it is on page 2:  www.mouser.com/ds/2/185/e60900232-38395.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean mechanical wear from the SD-Card slot itself?
That should be in the thousands.
Given the price of the rapi, I would guess the don't use a sturdy one.

If it somehow breaks, you can always replace it ;)

Comment: And make sure you have used Win32DiskImager so you have the contents safely stored on a hard drive for when that day comes.